# Why does std::sort compare the element to itself

Tags: c++, sorting, comparison

As the subject says, why does the below code compare some of the elements to themselves?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class a {
public:
    a(int value): value(value) {}
    ~a() {}

    bool operator<(const a& rhs) const {
        if(this->value == rhs.value)
            std::cout << this << " " << this->value << "\t" 
                << &rhs << " " << rhs.value << std::endl;
        if(this->value < rhs.value)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    int value;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<a> vec;

    for(int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
        vec.push_back(a(i));

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    return 0;
}
```

I tried the above code on Windows, Linux and OpenBSD, it seems on Windows it doesn't compare the element to itself, but both on Linux and OpenBSD it does. My guess is that it's because of different libraries being used.

On Linux I get output similar to this:

```
0x96be0d0 8     0xbfc2945c 8
0xbfc2945c 8    0x96be0d0 8
```

Comment: Different standard libraries implement their functions differently. That's all there is to it.

Comment: On my Linux box (GCC 4.8.1), the comparison predicate never compares items at the same address.

Comment: It's implementation defined. Implementations of `std::sort` may be different in different libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, though the question isn't really why there's a difference between libraries. It's why some libraries compare an element to itself. Obviously the element is not going to be smaller than the itself is. if(1 == 1) = pointless.

Comment: @larsmans Not sure I understand. The addresses in my output are also different, however it is comparing the element (with value 8) to itself, which is pointless.

Comment: Your class doesn't have an `==` operator, so how is `sort` supposed to tell that elements at different addresses are the same?

Comment: Youu'd could always compare the implementations; that could be educative. It is quite possible that this allows simpler code, and the effect on performance is "amortized zero"

Comment: @Barmar: Because they are the same input element?

Comment: It appears that temporary has been introduced that's why the addresses are different. Implementation does not seem to be optimized.

Comment: Why not? it doesn't cost the world, but avoiding it may.

Comment: @Walter How could avoiding self comparison cost the world? I mean by definition the answer would be 'false'? And it may cost the world in some situations, though those are probably rare. Besides, why not isn't really a good reason =)

Comment: Naively, `a < b` is less code than `&a == &b ? false : a < b`. It might incur the extra `&a == &b` test for _every_ comparison, just to avoid the `a < b` test for the small proportion of comparisons which are self-comparisons. This is in general not a good trade-off.

Comment: @Oktalist I don't think that would help, since it seems sort creates a copy which is then compared to the original, see the example output where the addresses are different. The self-comparison should be avoided by std::sort to begin with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should sorting algorithm pass same element in the comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966516/should-sorting-algorithm-pass-same-element-in-the-comparison-function)

Answer (score 2):

If `std::sort` is implemented as Quick sort, there is the case, that you compare the current element to the pivot element. I don't have my Sedgewick *Algorithms* at hand, but I think avoiding this comparison does not speed the algorithm up (or the comparison does no harm to the algorithms complexity). I can look the exact quote up, if you like.

Comment: `std::sort` is almost never implemented as a quicksort (technically).  It's _commonly_ implemented as a intro-sort, which is part-quicksort-part-heapsort-part-insertionsort.

Comment: "avoiding this comparison does not speed the algorithm up" can't possibly be true as a blanket statement.  Consider the case when the comparison function happens to be very expensive, and testing whether you're about to compare an element to itself is very cheap.  Then avoiding the comparison will indeed speed the algorithm up.